# How do I allow selecting folders from a folder/file selection dialog?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I can let users upload multiple files with HTML File Input.

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
```

Instead of just files, how do I let users upload an entire directory and its subdirectories with HTML/JavaScript?

I can only allow users to drag and drop folders which works fine but the users also need to be able to select entire folders with a folder/file selection dialog.

Dropbox has an **upload folder** feature as shown in the screenshot below.

[Folder Upload Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdyzl.png)

*Note: This is not a question concerning server side file uploading ability but just being able to select directory in the web browser.*

Answer (score 0):

In HTML file input upload, **a folder cannot be selected by default** instead, all files in the folder will be selected instead

Comment: I understand that and that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve but by letting users select a folder in order to extract its contents and not just files. Like dropbox's Upload Folder feature.